# jQuery Galleriffic Thumbnails Visited Border Colour

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have problem to change the border color of the visited thumbnails using Galleriffic. I use the option: Thumbnail rollover effects and slideshow crossfades, where I need to load the basic.css and galleriffic-2.css.

I want to change the black border for visited thumbnails to light color, such as light grey. However, I could not find any reference on both css files to change this. I notice in the basic.css this:

```
a:focus, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I did try to disable the above css script and added a:visited, none of them are working to change the color of visited thumbnails. I might miss something on this.

Is there anyone knows how to change the black border for visited thumbnails? Any help and thought would be appreciated.

Thanks heaps for your help.

**Edit: matthewpavkov request for code (14 Dec 10):**

matthewpavkov, at the moment I am still using the example code from Galleriffic to play around with the black border of the visited thumbnails:

The code for the example-2.html can be downloaded at: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/galleriffic-2.0.zip

I use 2 css files provided by galleriffic; basic.css and galleriffic-2.css. You can get these files from the zip files above. I can't put it here, because it's too long. Sorry for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution almost 3 weeks ago. Sorry for the delay for answering my own question. 
To change the border color for selected thumbnails, depending on which version you use, in my case is galleriffic-2.css, find the li.selected css and then change the background-color from black #000000 to any color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since Galleriffic in its simplest implementation does *not* change the URL, the `:visited` selector will not work. However, Galleriffic does have a [history plugin included](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-3.html), and when using that, the URL **does** get changed, allowing you to use CSS like this to get the desired effect:

```
a.thumb:visited {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, and it did not work. I also have another try again based on yours answer, and still no go. Since, I am thinking this must be done through css. The last 2 days, I absolutely can't find any reference that the black border for visited thumbnails have been done through css.

Comment: Hi matthewpavkov, I am still using the example-2.html to play with this. You can get the sample code on http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/galleriffic-2.0.zip. I use the basic.css and galleriffic-2.css for example-2.html.

Comment: @Arief Yes, I just took a look at it. I now realize that the problem is that there is no change in the URL (clicking on an image does not change anything in the URL). So, the `:visited` property won't work. However, if you use the history plugin (it should be integrated into Galleriffic), then the URL *will* change, and then the `:visited` property should work.

Comment: @matthewpavkov You're right. I did not realize that on too. Thank you so much for your help, I will try it shortly with the history plugin  included. Will advise the result. Thanks heaps once again.

Comment: @matthewpavkov Sadly, it did not work at all. The black border on selected thumbnails might not be a css. I am using example-3.html and play around with it, the black border still there.

Comment: @Arief Maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish. You said in your question "I want to change the black border for visited thumbnails". But your comment says "The black border on selected thumbnails". So, which one are you trying to change? The visited images (images that have already been clicked on) or the current image?

Comment: @matthewpavkov Sorry for confusing you about this. What I am talking about is the thumbnails, not the actual images. I want to change the black border around selected/visited thumbnails into something lighter. I used the term "visited" as I thought it's a css thing. However, I play around with example-3.html and implement your solution, it did not change the border color around the selected thumbnails.

Comment: @Arief Ok. The CSS I gave you will change the border around the thumbnails that you've clicked on. It will not change the border around the currently selected thumbnail. So, looking at the `example-3.html` file, and editing the `galleriffic-3.css` file using the CSS in my posted answer above, will change the border color around the thumbnails that you've already clicked on.

Comment: @matthewpavkov I did add your solution to the galleriffic-3.css. It did not change the border color around the thumbnails that I've clicked on. It is still black. Do I miss something here?

Comment: @Arief It works for me. Have a look: http://matthewpavkov.com/dev/temp/galleriffic/example-3.html

Comment: @matthewpavkov I tried yours, it's still black. What browser do you use for testing this? I try to open yours in Firefox and IE8, none of both browser change the border color of selected thumbnails.

Comment: @Arief You're right...doesn't work in IE8. It does work in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (I'm on a Mac). I have no idea why it's not working. I removed all the CSS from my example, and it still doesn't work. It's either a browser bug, or Galleriffic is doing something (or it could be the history plugin).

Comment: @matthewpavkov Your solution does not work in my Firefox as well, I use Win XP Prof SP3. This has made me going banana now with the border.

Comment: @Arief Yeah...it does work in Firefox on my Mac. My suspicions lie on something to do with the history plugin. The CSS is correct - that is not the problem. You could try looking for an answer on their blog: http://trentacular.com/2009/10/galleriffic-2-0/